# Question about color issues with the coffeescript REPL: Post on Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know whether my question belongs on Stack Overflow or Super User (or maybe even Unix & Linux?). Can you please take a look at my draft, and give a recommendation?

> The coffee-script REPL by default shows the output in yellow, which is
>   hardly readable when your background is white. Unfortunately, I
>   couldn't find a way to configure it, but I don't want to change my
>   background permanently to black just because of this issue.
>
> Do you know know whether the coffee REPL is configurable? If not, is
>   there an alternative? Disabling colored output completely would be
>   fine for me, too.
>
> I'm using Arch Linux and CoffeeScript version 1.6.2.

Comment: I vote for Stack Overflow, because it's [about "software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @RobW Good argument. I'll post to stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Rob W's argument to ask questions about [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) on stackoverflow.

Here is the question:
[Change the output color of the coffeescript REPL (no yellow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653082/change-the-output-color-of-the-coffeescript-repl-no-yellow)